# Круги своя

Tags: фонетика

Есть выражение из Библии "все вернется на круги своя", которое вошло в обычную речь и используется как фразеологизм.
Я слышала употребление с ударением "на крУги" и "на кругИ", но чаще все-таки "на крУги". А как правильно? И почему говорят с ударением на У?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно на крУги своЯ

Википедия

Происходит из Ветхого Завета (Книга Екклесиаста, глава 1, стих 6). Как и многие другие библейские выражения в русском языке получило распространение в форме, характерной для церковнославянского языка: форма множественного числа слова «свой» — «своя́» (вместо современного «свои́») и устаревшее ударение «кру́ги» (вместо современного «круги́»).

А. Галич

Мы проспали беду,
промотали чужое наследство,
жизнь подходит к концу,
и опять начинается детство,
пахнет мокрой травой
и махорочным дымом жилья,
продолжается детство без нас,
продолжается детство,
продолжается боль,
потому что ей некуда деться,
возвращается вечером ветер
на круги своя.